# How to make the fire mapper by using WebGIS?

Tags: hadoop, webserver

Now I have some test fire data and I want to make an internet based mapping tool that delivers locations of active fires in near real time, just like this:

https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/firemap/

I have searched some solutions, the most commonly used is Mapserver+QGIS or Geoserver+uDi, but I have no idea about these, can anybody give me some suggestions to make this fire mapper and the advantage and disadvantage about the softwares?